# line break and subscript in axis title using plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly

I just started to use `plotly` for some interactive scatter plots in R and having a hard time on axis labels. Normally I designed my plots with `ggplot2` and then using the `ggplotly` function to convert them, but this is sometimes very slow for any reason. So I want to create my plots directly in `plotly`...

I am trying now to change the axis title and want to add line breaks and later I also want to add subscript labels. But I am already failing at the newline in the title. Is there any trick?

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
plot_ly(mtcars, x = wt, y = mpg, text = rownames(mtcars), mode = "text") %>%
  layout(xaxis=list(title='text with\nlinebreak'))
```

Comment: Using the `%>%` operator with an interactive plot. Sounds pretty ... what's the right word... optimistic?

Comment: as I mentioned above... I just started to use `plotly` so I am open for suggestions. I also think the syntax is not so nice as `ggplot2` but what is the best way to get interactive plots for a shiny app? And don't tell me the answer is 42 :-)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In plotly, you can get linebreaks (and other text formatting) using html tags.

So piping

```
layout(xaxis=list(title='text with <br> linebreak'))
```

should work.

Hence, to get subscript labels use the `<sub>` tag. For example

```
CO<sub>2</sub>
```

will give you

CO<sub>2</sub>.

Comment: @M.A. do you know if this is supposed to work also in 3d plots? (you need usually the axis within the `scene` environment ) – it is not working in my case – thanks! (I am actually working in python)

Answer (score 4):

Note you have to use `<br>` or `<br />` not `<br/>` (without a space)

Comment: `<br />` should be fine. So it is XHTML and HTML conform...

Comment: oh nice @drmariod - thanks - updated the answer.