# Plotly: how to specify symbol and color based on value?

Tags: r, plotly

When plotting with `plotly` in R, how does one specify a color and a symbol based on a value? For example with the `mtcars` example dataset, how to plot as a red square if `mtcars$mpg` is greater or less than 18?

For example:

```
library(plotly)


p <- plot_ly(type = "scatter", data = mtcars, x = rownames(mtcars), y = mtcars$mpg,
             mode = "markers" )
```

How to get all points above 20 as yellow squares?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far. SO is ready to help, but please see the community guidelines for posting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @NateDay See updated question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
plot_ly(type = "scatter", data = mtcars, x = rownames(mtcars), y = mtcars$mpg,
        mode = "markers", symbol = ~mpg > 20, symbols = c(16,15),
        color = ~mpg > 20, colors = c("blue", "yellow"))
```

https://plot.ly/r/line-and-scatter/#mapping-data-to-symbols

yes it's possible, I'd make all of your grouping and shape/color specification outside of `plot_ly()` with `cut()` first. And then take advantage of the literal `I()` syntax inside of `plot_ly()` when referencing your new color and shape vars:

```
data(mtcars)

mtcars$shape <- cut(mtcars$mpg,
                    breaks = c(0,18, 26, 100),
                    labels = c("square", "circle", "diamond"))
mtcars$color <- cut(mtcars$mpg,
                    breaks = c(0,18, 26, 100),
                    labels = c("red", "yellow", "green"))

plot_ly(type = "scatter", data = mtcars, x = rownames(mtcars), y = mtcars$mpg,
        mode = "markers", symbol = ~I(shape), color = ~I(color))
```

Comment: Awesome! Can this be extended to include more? i.e. mpg 0-18 is red squares, mpg 19-25 is yellow circles, mpg 26+ is green diamonds? If so how would this look in the code?

Comment: is that possible..?

Comment: anything is possible, but sometimes my bill paying job gets in the way of SO

Comment: I just tried this with my own example, where the `breaks` would have to be much smaller numbers(0.01. 0.05), and it doesn't seem to work. Check out another question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44971581/r-abline-equivalent-in-plotly) if you'd like to help